# Logout of Microsoft in a React-Native Expo based application

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo, logout

I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions to implement a logout screen for a react-native expo based application. I'm working through the Microsoft Azure system and have login working fine. I cannot find much information readily available on the web about this and would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.